# Can cout sometimes be skipped or inputs be asked when not prompted in c++?

Tags: c++

Currently making a program for a "license plate game" (pretty much just words that contain the letters of a license plate, for example: if the license plate is "WRD 796", and the user's guess is "world", or "draw", then the user wins. If it's something like "truth", they lose.). I'm having issues with looping the program, and currently have everything working perfect for one loop, but messes up whenever i try to repeat it with a while loop containing a function asking the user if they want to play again. No syntax/#include errors or anything, using namespace std;

Here's my main:

```
#define STOP_STRING "detener"

int main(){
    string userGuess = "";
    do{
        string licensePlate = "", userGuess = "";

        getUserInputs(licensePlate, userGuess);
        licensePlate = trimLicensePlateNumbers(licensePlate);
        licensePlate = lowercaseTheUsersInputs(licensePlate, userGuess); 

        if(gameLoop(licensePlate, userGuess) ){
            break;
        }
        cin.ignore();
    }while(userWantsToPlayAgain(userGuess) );
}
```

and then the 3 functions that I think i have issues with:

```
void getUserInputs(string &licensePlate, string &userGuess){ //complete
    cout << "Enter a license plate: ";
    getline(cin,licensePlate);
    possiblePlatePermutations(licensePlate);
    cout << "Enter your guess. If you wish to stop guessing, say \"Detener\": ";
    getline(cin,userGuess);
    cout << endl;
    cin.clear(); 
}


bool gameLoop(string licensePlate, string &userGuess){
    bool userIsWrong = true;

    do{
        if(userGuess == STOP_STRING){
            return true; //allows the user to stop guessing and quit the game
        }
        else if(seeIfGuessMatchesLicensePlate(licensePlate, userGuess)){
            cout << "Your guess matches the license plate! " << endl << endl;
            userIsWrong = false;
        }
        else{
            cout << "WRONG!\t Please try another guess: ";
            cin >> userGuess;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cin.clear();
    }while(userIsWrong);
    return false;
}


bool userWantsToPlayAgain(string &userGuess){
    string playAgain;
    playAgain = userGuess;
    cout << "started userWantsToPlayAgain" << endl;
    
    if(playAgain == STOP_STRING){
        return false;
    }
    cout << "past the STOP_STRING (first one) " << endl;
    //still have issues getting the cout/first cin
    
    cout << "Would you like to play again? Say \"Detener\" if you wish to stop: "; //RIGHT HERE, LOOK HERE
    cin >> playAgain;
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < playAgain.size(); i++){
        playAgain[i] = tolower(playAgain[i]);
    }
    
    if(playAgain == STOP_STRING){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Somehow, the "cout << "Would you like to play again? Say "Detener" if you wish to stop: "; " (exclamation points just to make it stand out) is displaying AFTER some input. So the user inputs the license plate, their guess, guess is correct, and then issues show up. There's a empty input with no cout, if you hit enter or type anything, it then outputs that cout in userWantsToPlayAgain() I emphasized, and then the cin >> playAgain; If you type in anything before userWantsToPlayAgain() where its for some reason  asking for a input despite me never calling for one (I think), it will return the first character as playAgain (found with a debug statement I deleted), but if nothing is inputed then it just skips over and the program starts again, with the licensePlate getline(cin, licensePlate) input in getUserInputs being skipped, but the userGuess input working.

I'm thinking there's some issue with cin buffering, but I have no clue where or how to fix it. I've been stuck on this for a week straight and have no clue how to fix it.

I've tried using cin.ignore()/cin.clear() in case that was the issue, or changing the way my program loops, but none of that would work

Comment: Make things easy on people, including yourself, with a [mre].

Comment: Could be [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) Gotta be very careful when mixing those.